# matplotlib в python 3.5: ошибка DLL load failed

Tags: python, python-3.5

Установил matplotlib win 64 для python 3.5 при наборе простого кода:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

Выдает данную ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Kulnevich/PycharmProjects/untitled1/example.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   File "C:\Users\Kulnevich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 29, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar   File "C:\Users\Kulnevich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.artist as martist   File "C:\Users\Kulnevich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .transforms import (Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox,   File "C:\Users\Kulnevich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 39, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox, ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
```

Установленный модуль проверял в папке, все в порядке установлен, в чем же проблема?

Comment: Если вопрос решён, то нажмите на галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: Как вы его устанавливали?
В каталоге C:\Users\Kulnevich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib какие файлы DLL и PYD есть?

Answer (score 2):

Не соответствует разрядность установленной библиотеки и Python.
Скорее всего у вас установлен только Python x86.

Если, все же, установлены верные версии попробуйте переустановить Python и поставить matplotlib с помощью команды: `pip install matplotlib`

Answer (score -1):

Мне помогло на WIN7, когда я обновил Microsoft Visual Studio C++ Redistributable Package 14.29.30129.1

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос